# How to attach raw sql code into an eloquent query

Tags: eloquent, sql-server-2012, migration, laravel-8, php-8

I'm running migrations in Laravel. Database is in Microsoft Server 2012.

There is a field 'ZoneId' that must autoincrement, but must NOT be primary key.

I've tried declaring it as incremental, and then drop the key. This works in MySql, but not in MsSql.

Way to do this with raw MsSql code in SQL Server:

```
ALTER Table Zone add ZoneId BIGINT NOT NULL UNIQUE IDENTITY(1,1);
```

Now, Laravel uses Eloquent, and I want to use the less amount possible of raw code in my project.

So, this declaration:

```
$table->bigInteger('ZoneId');
```

Already translates into this:

```
ALTER Table Zone add ZoneId BIGINT NOT NULL UNIQUE
```

What I need now is to attach the last part that makes it incremental:

```
IDENTITY(1,1)
```

Something like:

```
$table->bigInteger('ZoneId')->**attach**('IDENTITY(1,1)')
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Im not sure about mssql, but normally i would use `$table->bigInteger('ZoneId')->autoIncrement()` to achieve what you want to achieve in mysql. Maybe this function translates into your request to mssql?:)

Comment: or `$table->bigIncrements('ZoneId')` if you are not updating but defining

Comment: If I define an autoincrementable field, it will automatically be set as primary key... And then I can't drop it, cause msserver won't allow me. And MS won't allow me because it creates it's own primary key name, so in the eyes of MS it's not 'ZoneId' anymore, it becomes something like 'PK__Zone__601667B57C2ED741'.
So when I do:
```
$table->dropPrimary('ZoneId');
```
The DB has no idea what I'm talking about.
Maybe somebody has an idea of how can I get the primary key name that MS creates, I honestly have no idea...